# Overriding max-width (or scaling up a small image for mobile)

Tags: email, mailchimp, css

I'm working on a responsive email using Mailchimp and all images are scaling down fine except for an image which has to have max-width set to 160px. This comes up fine on desktop but on mobile displays smaller than 100% width.

I've set up the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    img[class=mcnImage] {
        width:100% !important;
```

But it still comes up too small. Any ideas?

Comment: `img[class=mcnImage]`? Do `img.mcnImage`. The `.` is a class selector.` You also should only sparingly if *ever* need `|important`. Have you read any about how to calculate the precedence of a selector?

Comment: [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 1):

As my comments above state, there's possibly a couple of things that could be legitimately getting in the way here. However, this is pure speculation, but consider for a moment...

**CSS**

```
img[class=one] {
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50" class="one"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50" class="one "/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50" class=" one"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50" class=" one "/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50" class="one two"/>
```

Before seeing what happens on the fiddle, first see if you can figure out what *should* happen (if you're familiar with the `[]` attribute selector).

Think you got it? Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/RxVE5/).

`img[class=term]` not only is *unnecessary* (class selecting with `img.term` *works perfectly*), but it only selects *one* of the images. `[attr=term]` matches on an exactly statement, no whitespaces or anything. I don't know if that' srelated, but it's worth noting. nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

agree with above comment that you should follow this standard way to refer the elements.. but for the solution of your problem, you can try adding `max-width:auto` to your code;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    img[class=mcnImage] {
        width:100% !important;
        max-width:auto;
    }
}
```